# How to fix a violation of the DRY principle?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, dry

```
    public Token match(ITokenType expectedToken, int tokenNum) {
        if(hasToken(_currentTokenNum))
            if(expectedToken == getToken(tokenNum).get_type())
                return getToken(tokenNum);
        return null;
    }

    public Token match(Class<?> clazz, int tokenNum) {
        if(hasToken(_currentTokenNum))
            if(clazz.isInstance(getToken(tokenNum).get_type()))
                return getToken(tokenNum);
        return null;
    }
```

I tried to make a single match method, and put the condition into two methods, but it didn’t work out.

Comment: How is `ITokenType` defined? The problem is that you have two separate methods. If you are looking to simplify you should remove one of the two methods and have one way of matching token.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, Didn't quite understand the question "How is ITokenType defined?". But I need both methods.

Comment: The methods look sufficiently distinct (one checking for reference-equality via `==` on the `type`-attribute, one checking for inheritance-relationship via `isInstance()` on the `type` attribute) that I do not see any reason to dry them. I would even suggest renaming both methods to better reflect their semantics.

Comment: @Turing85, Something like matchByType and matchByValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the duplication like this:

```
    public Token match(ITokenType expectedToken, int tokenNum) {
        return match(t -> expectedToken == t.get_type(), tokenNum)
    }

    public Token match(Class<?> clazz, int tokenNum) {
        return match(t -> clazz.isInstance(t.get_type()), tokenNum);
    }

    public Token match(Predicate<Token> predicate, int tokenNum) {
        if(hasToken(_currentTokenNum)) {
            Token t = getToken(tokenNum);
            if (predicate.test(t))
                return t;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The condition which needs to be tested is passed in as a `Predicate` (as it can't be evaluated until we've checked `hasToken`).

Whether the loss of readability is worth the reduction in duplication is uncertain.

If we had many places, or widely separated places, where we were duplicating this code (rather than two, in the same class), then we are likely to change one place and not the other when requirements change.

If the implementation of `match` was more complicated, then we are likely to get some of the changes wrong, even if we find all the places.

In this case it probably isn't worth removing the duplication.